# Netbeans Issue Duplicate Error

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have downloaded: XQuartz, Xcode, and Netbeans 7.4. I am trying to run a simple program. I created a new project correctly with direction from Netbeans website, and I am getting an error found below for this code:

```
#include <iostream>    /* Include header file to do input and output */
#include <fstream>     /* Include the library to read and write files */
#include <iomanip>    /* Include the library that allows formatting  */
#include <cmath>       /*Include the math library */
using namespace std;   /*Allow operations from standard library */

int main()
{
    cout << "Clarissa Danif hw1bCD.cpp GE 1111- M, W, TH 10:30 \n" << endl; 
    ofstream outfile;                /* Declare the variables to write to a file */
    outfile.open("hw1bCD.txt");     /* Open output file to write to */ 
    //Variables usnames:
    double m;
    double n;
    // C++ c
    cout << "Please enter the base number\n";
    cin>> m; 
    cout<< "Please enter the power\n";
    cin>> n;
    // Start the if loop
    if (m<0 || n<0)
    {
       cout<< "Error, please enter positive integers";
    } 
    else 
    {
       cout<< "m^n =  "<<pow(m,n)<<"\n";
    }
    // C++ c
    cout << "Please enter the base number\n";
    cin>> m;
    cout<< "Please enter the power\n";
    cin>> n;
    outfile << "Base is " <<m<< " and exponent power is " << n << ".\n"; 
    // Start the if loop
    if (m<0 || n<0)
    {
       cout<< "Error, please enter positive integers";
     } 
     else 
    {
    cout<< "m^n =  "<<pow(m,n)<<"\n";
    outfile << "m^n =  " <<pow(m,n)<< ".\n"; 
    }
    // C++ c
     cout << "Please enter the base number\n";
    cin>> m;
    cout<< "Please enter the power\n";
    cin>> n;
    outfile << "Base is " <<m<< " and exponent power is " << n << ".\n"; 
    // Start the if loop
    if (m<0 || n<0)
    {
       cout<< "Error, please enter positive integers";
    } 
    else 
    {
       cout<< "m^n =  "<<pow(m,n)<<"\n";
       outfile << "m^n =  " <<pow(m,n)<< ".\n"; 
    }
    system("pause"); //To hold dos window
    return 0;
} //To close main function
```

**The error is below:**

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hwtest
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hwtest build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hwtest.o build/Debug/GNU-           MacOSX/main.o 
duplicate symbol _main in:
build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hwtest.o
build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hwtest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: It looks like the linker is finding a main method in hwtest.o and main.o. That would indicate your main.cc file is including hwtest.cc or hwtest.h which also contains a main method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you remove personal details from your code before posting it. On a separate not, you will get better answers if you provide a minimal example of your problem. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://www.sscce.org/